# XCode 6.3.1 - lost connection to attached device frequently

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, xcode6.3

When running my App, I'll get this occur 3 out of 4 attempts to run the app from xcode.  Hitting enter & CMD-R will sometimes generate the error again, and sometimes (rarely) actually run & debug the code.  This happens with both an iPhone 6 device (8.3) and a iPhone 5 device (8.2).

[image]

While it's not a show stopper, its adding to the development cycle time.  Anyone out there suffering the same issue, or anyone have a solution?

I've had this happen both with and without a watch extension, but it is more pronounced when working on an App with a watch extension.

Comment: I get this the first time I try to run a test after I've just recently reopened xcode

Answer (score 0):

While Watch connections can be inconsistent, it seems that keeping the Watch on the charger while debugging is a noticeable improvement. That's been my experience along with others who have comment in the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: My watch is sitting on it's charger & the phone is connected directly to the back of the mac...

Comment: I get the same error, even under these conditions. I don't know of anyone who doesn't have the occasional lost connection with WatchKit development.

Comment: I understand that Mike - I've had issues with XCode when developing on both a device & the simulator, but this is beyond occasional - it can happen 3 or 4 times in a row, before it runs the code correctly.  Appreciate the feedback - just wish it was something I could easily fix.

Answer (score 0):

So here's my ritual on a "quick" turnaround for build & runs:

- Open your app on the Watch
- Press and hold the button below the crown until the Power Off options appear
- Release the button and press and hold again. This will terminate the running app.
- Build & Run from Xcode
- On the Debug Navigator it will hang 9/10 times at the "Waiting to Attach" screen
- Help Xcode a little bit by tapping on your app icon from your Watch home screen to open it, Xcode will promptly attach.
- Your new build is now running.

I really hope they fix this in the next Xcode update but this is how it's currently working for me.